# How do apps get attached images to tweets when using twitter api?

Tags: javascript, twitter

I want to display images attached to tweets next to each tweet if available (I think all links go something like pic.twitter.com). I can think only of one example when this is done which is on Flipboard but I'm sure it's a common practice, however I couldn't find info in twitter documentation on how to do it. Does somebody know how this can be done?

This is how I commonly retrieve tweets in my app:

```
function searchTwitter(query) {
    alert(jQuery.param(query));
    $.ajax({
        url: 'http://search.twitter.com/search.json?q=pizza',
        dataType: 'jsonp',
        success: function(data) {
            var tweets = $('#tweets');
            tweets.html('');
            for (res in data['results']) {
                tweets.append('<div class="tweet"><p>' + data['results'][res]['text'] + '</p> <div class="accountName"> by ' + data['results'][res]['from_user'] + '</div></div>');
            }
        }
    });
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Look at the documentation here](https://dev.twitter.com/docs/tweet-entities).

Specifically the part about **Media Entities**, there are various urls there.

all you need to do is get that url, and put it in an `<img>` tag, and the browser should fetch it for you.

Alternatively, depending on the rest of your code, you could set the background-image css property to the url.

Comment: Can you upload an example to do it?

Comment: The documentation has moved to [this URL](https://dev.twitter.com/overview/api/entities-in-twitter-objects#media).